# How to use scope variable in template script after the controller is loaded?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to access a variable in scope to use it later (this is an example)
if I insert a setTimeout function it works well, but if I try in this way it prints "undefined" to console. How can I wait till the controller is loaded?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var scope = angular.element(document.querySelector('#test')).scope();
    console.log(scope.test);
}
```

EDIT: i'm using [AnnotatorPro](https://codecanyon.net/item/annotator-pro-image-tooltips-zooming/9788132), so i need to call

```
$("#map").annotatorPro(test);
```

on:

```
<img id="map" src="map.svg">
```

Comment: If you use an angular component you can access the controllers $onInit method which is only called once the component has fully loaded.

Comment: If using AngularJS you should avoid jQuery selectors and methods because your views might not be refreshed on certain conditions. Use this instead:
`angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = 'Hello';
    });`

Comment: My advice is if you are using Angular don't use jQuery at all - or if you have to for something put it in a directive. You should very, very rarely (if ever) need to access an HTML element like this. Instead you should be using Angular's data binding.

Comment: @MarcoLigabue First of all you need a directive for the plugin. Then why are you doing all this? move all this logic to the parent controller, there the scope variables will be accessible. Can you provide more code, like what calls the template and the parent controller?